# aFrame Mobile, staying in VR?

Tags: aframe

When using aframe on mobile and going from page to page I want it to stay in VR mode after the user clicks the VR icon in aframe.

However at the moment whenever you go from one page to another it kicks the user out of vr and the address bar appears so you have to manually click the VR button everytime you want to enter fullscreen again.

Is there a solution to this?

You can check out my aframe application below:

https://www.360belfast.com/app/options.html

I've read desktop solutions online but not much for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. On mobile, A-Frame relies on fullscreen mode that doesn't persist on navigation. It has to be triggered by user gesture on each individual site. It's a browser policy that cannot be worked around. In-VR navigation is only available with a supported headset on Firefox and Supermedium on desktop, and Oculus Browser and Samsung Internet on standalone headsets.

Comment: I see, appreciate the response. Is the Gear VR headset with a Samsung phone supported?

Comment: Maybe, I don’t have one to test at the moment